# How to remove more than one symbol from csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to replace my **old**.csv data that looks like this: `6004387,6219127,'12524449',10340`

Into **new**.csv that **should look like this**:  `6004387|6219127|12524449|10340`

What I get now is `"['6004387'| '6219127'| ""'12524449'""| '10340']"`

How can I remove more than one symbol?

```
import csv
import string

input_file = open('old.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('new.csv', 'w')
data = csv.reader(input_file)
writer = csv.writer(output_file)
specials = ','

for row in data:
    row = str(row)
    new_row = str.replace(row,specials,'|')
    writer.writerow(new_row.split(','))

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove quote characters from input file, specify `quotechar="'"` in `csv.reader`. Also, for `|` delimiter in output file, specify `delimiter='|'` in `csv.writer`:

```
import csv

input_file = open('old.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('new.csv', 'w')
data = csv.reader(input_file, quotechar="'")
writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter='|')

for row in data:
    writer.writerow(row)

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Creates `new.csv`:

```
6004387|6219127|12524449|10340
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `|` as the delimeter and then recurively remove unwanted characters afterwards with a function such as `str.strip("\"' ")` [which removes all characters from the string which match what's in the brackets.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)